# Argument 'myAppController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I want to inject my service into my controller and just see my console log (in the Auth Service), but I'm getting this error: Argument 'myAppController' is not a function, got undefined. What am I doing wrong?

In my main.js file I have:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

myApp.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', function($scope, AuthService) {
    console.log('controller');
    AuthService.console();
    ...
```

In my services.js file I have:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('AuthService', function(){
    this.console = function(){
        console.log('in the AuthService');
    }
});
```

Loading the files in my index.html file as:

```
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotta declare it as a string too for the injection:

```
myApp.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', 'AuthService', function($scope, AuthService) {
```

Comment: Got it! It looks like I don't need to redeclare myApp in the service. So I don't need this line: var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]); in the service file

Comment: Still good practice to use `var myApp = angular.module('myApp');`. Just without the empty parameter list to tell Angular to use the existing myApp instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

**Define MyApp Like this**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

myApp.controller('myAppController', function ($scope, ajaxService) {

        ajaxService.ajaxGetWithData(url).then(function (data) {
            $scope.Data= data;
        });

});


app.service('ajaxService', function ($http, $q) {

   this.ajaxGetWithData = function (url) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'POST', url: url, data: $.param(User),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=UTF-8' },
        })
            .success(function (data) {

                if (data != null) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }

            })
            .error(function (err) {

                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```